# Please explain these counter-interpretations to these Natural Deduction arguments

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, examples-counterexamples, first-order-logic, natural-deduction

I have attached a screenshot of the arguments, but here they are written out just in case. I am able to prove when sentences are equivalent, but could somebody please explain the counter-interpretations to me?

I understand that, since its a counterinterpretation, they have opposite truth-values, but I don't understand how the use of numbers reflect truth-values. For example, in the first question, since "" names 1, how do I understand "" ? How does the predicate  act upon "", and what is the significance of "" symbolising 1? Also, still in the first question, there is no  in either sentence, so what relevance does it have to the question? I am unsure of the use of numbers as counterexamples in general. I hope that clarifies my question.

> Argument: $∀xPx → Qc,∀x(Px → Qc)$ Counter-interpretation: let the
> domain be the numbers 1 and 2. Let $‘c’$ name 1. Let $‘Px’$ be true of
> and only of 1. Let $‘Qx’$ be true of, and only of, 2.
>
> Argument: $∀x∀y∀zBxyz$,$∀xBxxx$ Counter-interpretation: let the domain
> be the numbers 1 and 2. Let ‘$Bxyz$’ be true of, and only of, ⟨1,1,1⟩
> and ⟨2,2,2⟩.
>
> Argument: $∃x∀yDxy$,$∀y∃xDxy$ Counter-interpretation: let the domain
> be the numbers 1 and 2. Let $‘Dxy’$ hold of and only of ⟨1,2⟩ and
> ⟨2,1⟩. This is depicted thus: 1 ↔ 2
>
> Argument: $∀x(Rca ↔ Rxa)$, $Rca ↔ ∀xRxa$ Counter-interpretation:
> consider the following diagram, allowing $‘a’$ to name 1 and ‘c’ to
> name 2: The diagram is of 1 with an arrow from itself pointing to
> itself, and 2 with no arrows.

[image: ![![enter image description here]

Comment: Under each given counterinterpretation, the two sentences have opposite truth values. If you require more elaboration, then please first elaborate on your thoughts and ideas and difficulty with the exercise. Welcome to this site! Please also enclose mathematics within dollar signs: `$∀xPx → Qc$` displays as $ ∀xPx→Qc.$

Comment: Have done! I understand that, since its a counterinterpretation, they have opposite truth-values, but I don't understand how the use of numbers reflect truth-values. For example, in the first question, since $"c"$ names 1, how do I understand $"Qc"$ ? How does the predicate $Q$ act upon $"c"$, and what is the significance of $"c"$ symbolising 1? Also, still in the first question, there is no $Qx$ in either sentence, so what relevance does it have to the question? I am unsure of the use of numbers as counterexamples in general. I hope that clarifies my question - thanks for getting back to me!

Answer (score 1):

> For example, in the first question, since "c" names 1, how do I
> I don't understand how the use of numbers reflect truth-values.
> For example, in the first question, since "c" names 1, how do I
> understand "Qc" ? How does the predicate Q act upon "c", and what is
> the significance of "c" symbolising 1? Also, still in the first
> question, there is no Qx in either sentence, so what relevance does it
> have to the question?  I am unsure of the use of numbers as
> counterexamples in general. I hope that clarifies my question

I'll elaborate on the first two given solutions by way of answering the above.

> Argument: $$∀xPx → Qc,\quad∀x(Px → Qc)$$

Note that the screenshot doesn't actually use word "argument", and your introducing it during transcribing is a mistake: the given is merely a pair of sentences to be compared, rather than to be joined by a conditional (namely, an argument).

> Counter-interpretation: let the domain be the numbers $1$ and $2.$

- Each variable (e.g., $x$) is an element of $\{1,2\}.$

> Let ‘$c$’ name $1.$

- Weird phrasing; I presume that $c$ is a constant of value $1.$

> Let ‘$Px$’ be true of and only of $1.$ Let ‘$Qx$’ be true of, and only of, $2.$

- $P=\{1\}, Q=\{2\};$ that is, $P1,Q2$ are true and $P2,Q1$ false. $P2$
  is commonly written as $P(2)$.

Hence, $$∀xPx → Qc$$ becomes False→False, while putting $x{=}1$ into $Px → Qc$ shows that $$∀x(Px → Qc)$$ is true/false?

> Argument: $$∀x∀y∀zBxyz,\quad∀xBxxx$$
> Counter-interpretation: let the domain be the numbers $1$ and $2.$ Let
> ‘$Bxyz$’ be true of, and only of, $⟨1,1,1⟩$ and $⟨2,2,2⟩.$

- $x,y,z\in\{1,2\},\quad B=\{(1,1,1),(2,2,2)\}.$

Left-hand side: put $(x,y,z){=}(1,2,2).$

Right-hand side: can $Bxxx$ be falsified?

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer! However, since  is true of and only of 1, and  is true of and only of 2, if we set  as 1 and  as 1, doesn't the conditional (∀→) have a true antecedent and false consequent, and therefore a false overall truth value? Isn't ∀ satisfied by =1 and  not satisfied by =1, since  is only satisfied by 2? Also, shouldn't the same truth-values hold for ∀(→)?

Comment: Regarding the second question, I understand how the left-hand side can be falsified. Since ={(1,1,1),(2,2,2)}, can I falsify the right-hand side by picking variables that are not {(1,1,1),(2,2,2)}, so for example, put (,,)=(1,1,2)?

Comment: @NorpellWilberforce 1. I made a small mistake that caused you confusion; click on 'edited __ ago' to see what I've just changed.  $\quad\quad$   2. "*If we set $$ as $1,$ isn't $∀$ true?*" $\;\;\textbf{∀x}$ means that $$ is true **for all** $\mathbf x.\quad\quad$   3. "*Can can I falsify $B$ by picking $(,,)=(1,1,2)$ ?*"$\;\;$ Look at the formula $B\textbf{xxx}$ carefully.

Comment: Ah, I understand the first question now -  ∀ is not true, since  is true only if  is 1, whereas the domain states that it could be 2. However, I am still unsure about the second - what is the significance of ={(1,1,1),(2,2,2)}? Since all the variables that  is acting on are the same, i.e. , how can the value of  not be either {(1,1,1),(2,2,2)}?

Comment: Thank you for bearing with me!

Comment: @NorpellWilberforce Exactly! The answer to your question "Can can I falsify Bxxx by picking (x,y,z)=(1,1,2) ?" is thus No. Are you perhaps forgetting that your goal is to show that the left and right formulae are not logically equivalent, that is, that they have opposite truth values?

Comment: Ah, then, seeing as the left formula is false and I thus want the right one to be true, given that ={(1,1,1),(2,2,2)}, should I set  as 1?

Comment: @NorpellWilberforce "*I thus want the right one to be true*" $\quad$ RHS *already is* true under the given countermodel (again: **∀ S** in plain English means “S is true **for EACH **”); it's not that you **want** RHS to be true; it's that you **want to show that** RHS is true; you do this by considering ALL the possibilities for x, rather than by “setting” x to be any *particular* number.  (On the other hand, to prove that THERE EXISTS x such that Sx is true, then yes you set x to be whichever value makes Sx true.)

Comment: Then do I show that  cannot be falsified by inputting 1, and then 2, showing that   is true for each of them, and thereby that  is true on every interpretation in the domain? My problem is trying to do this formally - do I go by a tertium non datur way and try to set it out in a Fitch-style natural deduction proof?

Comment: @NorpellWilberforce Edit to my previous comment: "it's not that you **want** RHS to be true; it's that you **want to convince yourself that** RHS is true **in the given countermodel**; you do this by considering ALL the possibilities for x".   To repeat:  please do not forget that your goal (why you posted this Question in the first place) is to merely convince yourself that the left and right formulae in the given countermodel have opposite truth values.